# Element-wise logical AND on indeterminate number of Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say that I have a list/iterable of n (where n is unknown to the function) Pandas Series that represent logical boolean indexes and I'd like to AND all of them element-wise and use the resulting Series to index a DataFrame.

Currently I'm using `np.logical_and(x1,x2)` and a for loop to do this.  I didn't have much luck using `itertools.izip` or `zip`.  The pandas.Series object didn't seem to like being operated upon by them.

I've been scratching my head for awhile now about what I may not be seeing about why this seems to result in a Series of booleans but I then get `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided` upon execution.

Any thoughts?  I feel like since these are `ndarray` that there has to be some obviously clean way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming I understand you, you can use `logical_and.reduce`.  Starting from a list of Series:

```
>>> ss = [pd.Series([ True, False,  True, False,  True]), pd.Series([False,  True,  True, False, False]), pd.Series([False, False,  True, False,  True]), pd.Series([False,  True,  True, False, False]), pd.Series([ True,  True,  True,  True, False])]
```

which would look like

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(ss)
       0      1     2      3      4
0   True  False  True  False   True
1  False   True  True  False  False
2  False  False  True  False   True
3  False   True  True  False  False
4   True   True  True   True  False

[5 rows x 5 columns]
```

if it were a dataframe, you can reduce across the columns:

```
>>> np.logical_and.reduce(ss)
array([False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

or pass `axis=1` if you want the other direction.

Remember that you can also use `any` and `all`, e.g.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(ss)
>>> df.all()
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
dtype: bool
```