# pandas series filtering between values

Tags: python, pandas

If `s` is a [`pandas.Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#series), I know I can do this:

```
b = s < 4
```

or

```
b = s > 0
```

but I can't do

```
b = 0 < s < 4
```

or

```
b = (0 < s) and (s < 4)
```

What is the idiomatic pandas method for creating a boolean series based on the logical AND / OR / NOT of other boolean series?

Comment: I don't know about pandas, but numpy has `logical_and` -- and the `&` operator also works with booleans IIRC... e.g. `np.logical_and(0 < s, s < 4)` or `(0 < s) & (s < 4)`.  If the arrays are type boolean, the bitwise and operator gives you an array of bools.  Otherwise, you'll get an array of something else (so I prefer not to use it).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23418393/748858 might be of help as well.

Comment: You have to use the array operators: `b = (0 < s) & (s < 4)` as you have to compare all values in the array

Comment: yeah, just figured that out, I had been missing the parentheses using `&` when I tried it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found it... the `&` operator works, but you need to use parentheses to get the precedence right and avoid an error:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s1 = pd.Series([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4])
>>> (s1 < 4) & (s1 > 0)
0     False
1      True
2      True
3      True
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8      True
9      True
10     True
11    False
dtype: bool
>>> s1 < 4 & s1 > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\app\python\anaconda\1.6.0\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
line 698, in __nonzero__
    .format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `.between`:

```
s1.between(0, 4, inclusive=False)
```

A bit verbose but as it doesn't have to create 2 intermediary series it should be faster (admittedly untested).

Comment: I did a comparison using the ipython '%timeit' magic command, the two methods are within 1% of each other's time.  So, at least for small dataframes, their performance is nearly identical.